# BEDMAS precedence in (Obj-)C?

Tags: objective-c, c, math, floating-point

I've just solved a rather weird problem I've been having in an iOS Application. I need to apply a scaling factor (which I have calculated to be `64/38 ~= 1.684`), to a value passed into a method.

The crux of my problem looks like this:

```
- (void)applyScaleTo:(int)value {

    // value := 64
    int first = value * (64/38)
    NSLog(@"First: %d", first);
    int second = (64 * value)/38;
    NSLog(@"Second: %d", second);

}
```

The desired value is `107`, but the logs look like this:

```
First: 64
Second: 107
```

My solution is to use the second method, which is fine, but my question is, why this discrepancy? (Incidentally, if `first` is changed to a `float`, it still logs as `64.00000...`.)

Comment: 64/38, as the operands are ints, is 1 - changing the result to a float does not change the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you divide two integers (64 and 38) which give you an integer value back (1).
To correct that you don't have to change the result value to a float (this will merely convert your integer result of 64 to a float), but at least one of your operants of the division.

```
int first = value * ( (float) 64 / 38)
```

This should give you 107 as a result

Comment: Note that you could also simply declare the 64 as a float constant by writing as 64.f. Also either approach, as written, will generate a warning as the result is implicitly cast back to an int.